# How do i use Dark Sky API with livecode?

Tags: android, ios, json, api, livecode

I am a beginner with livecode and i can't for the life of me figure out how to call for the API and use the data that it gives me. I have integrated the easyjson script in my stack and pasted the

" $_GET https://api.darksky.net/forecast/secretkeyhere/37.8267,-122.4233 "

and i get nothing. I am probably missing alot but i don't know how to get it to work, i've googled alot and to be honest there isn't that much about livecode stuff...

My goal is to create a weather app

Answer (score 0):

$_GET is a LiveCode server-only construct. If you want to get data back from a web service API in a LiveCode stack, use a standard `put` statement, with the `URL` keyword:

```
put URL "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/secretkeyhere/37.8267,-122.4233" into tWeatherData
```

This is how you execute a GET method with a RESTful API. To use a POST method, use the LC `post` command:

```
# first construct the argument string
put "name=" & urlEncode("value string here") into tArgs
post tArgs to URL "http://api.base.url"
put it into tSomeVariable
```

I put together a lesson on how to access RESTful APIs in LiveCode here:

http://livecode.byu.edu/internet/webServicesIntro.php

*Edit*

Once you have downloaded the data you simply parse out what you want to display and show it in a text field. In the case of darksky.net, the data is sent as JSON text, so you can use LiveCode's JSON library to convert it to an array.

```
put JSONimport(tWeatherData) into tWeatherArray
put tWeatherArray["currently"]["temperature"] && "degrees and" \
  && tForecastArray ["currently"]["icon"] into field "currentWeather"
```

Comment: I've managed to access the API now and i get the degrees and if it's cloudy clear etc, but how do i make it show automatically on the card? Right now the data just comes in a pop up window if i press a button.

I did like this:

on mouseUp
   
get url 

"https://api.darksky.net/forecast/secreykeyhere/59.334591,18.063240"
  
 put it into tForecast  
   
put JSONimport(tForecast) into tForecastArray

   answer "It is currently"&&tforecastarray[currently][temperature]&&"degrees and"&&tforecastarray[currently][icon]

end mouseUp

Comment: Using an answer command will show the results in a modal dialog. Instead, just create a field to display the weather data. Let's say, field "currentWeather". Replace the `answer` statement with `put tForecastArray["currently"]["temperature"] && "degrees and" && tForecastArray ["currently"]["icon"] into field "currentWeather" `.